# INDIRECT adds quotation marks on cell address

Tags: excel, vba

There is no error when I run this code. But the output on the validation formula is `=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE("A10"," ","_"),"-","_"),"/","_"),"(",""),")",""))` where the range is "A10" and what I need is to have that range only without the quotation mark so it can show the dropdown menu. I tried different combination and head starts to ache.

Here is my code:

```
               Formu1 = ActiveCell.Offset(1, -12).Address(False, False)
            With Range(Formu1).Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Name_Range"
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With

            Formu2 = ActiveCell.Offset(1, -10).Address(False, False)
            offsetter = ActiveCell.Offset(1, -12).Address(False, False)

            With Range(Formu2).Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Formula1:="=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(""" _
                & offsetter & ""","" "",""_""),""-"",""_""),""/"",""_""),""("",""""),"")"",""""))"
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With
```

Comment: I can easily give you the answer but let's see if you can get it own your own :) What do you think `"=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(""" _
                & offsetter & ""","" "",""_""),""-"",""_""),""/"",""_""),""("",""""),"")"",""""))"` part does?

Comment: specially `""" _ & offsetter & """` part

Comment: @SiddharthRout making it `range(offsetter)` should solve the problem but I still get an error when doing it.

Comment: No that is not what I mean. You have extra quotes around the cell address. The clue lies in my second comment above :)

Comment: I tried doing it with `" & range(offsetter) & "` but doing it with double quotation mark will render an error even without running the code.

Comment: What happens when you change `""" _ & offsetter & """` to `" _ & offsetter & "`?

Comment: After changing it to `" _ & offsetter & "` I would get a Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: Can you type here the exact formula that you want in the validation?

Comment: One Moment.. Posting an answer

Comment: @SiddharthRout `=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A10," ","_"),"-","_"),"/","_"),"(",""),")",""))` The code works and it puts the validation on the cell but the problem is the output is `=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE("A10"," ","_"),"-","_"),"/","_"),"(",""),")",""))` where the range has quotation marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one problem with the formula. and that is that you have Extra quotes in the formula itself.

```
""" _ & offsetter & """
```

So use this

```
"=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(" _
& offsetter & _
","" "",""_""),""-"",""_""),""/"",""_""),""("",""""),"")"",""""))"
```

Now This formula will give you a `#REF!` error if the `OUTPUT` inside the `=INDIRECT(OUTPUT)` doesn't evaluate to a valid range.

**Demonstration**

Let's say your worksheet looks like this

[image]

Now try this code

```
offsetter = "A10"

With Range("B1").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:= _
    "=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(" _
    & offsetter & _
    ","" "",""_""),""-"",""_""),""/"",""_""),""("",""""),"")"",""""))"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

**Output**

[image]

**Explanation**

In the above code `SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(" & offsetter & ","" "",""_""),""-"",""_""),""/"",""_""),""("",""""),"")"","""")` evaluates to `My_Range` and hence you get the right value `=Index("My_Range")`. If it evaluated to say `Sidd` then `=Index("Sidd")` would give an error as there is no range `Sidd`

Comment: I have tried this before I asking the question and I also tried it again but no good. The code `"=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(""" _ & offsetter & ""","" "",""_""),""-"",""_""),""/"",""_""),""("",""""),"")"",""""))"` is working but the validation formula has `...Substitute("A10"," ","_")...` where the range has extra quotation. making it single quotation or double still renders an error. From what I think, making it `Range(offsetter)` would solve the problem but still no luck. Thanks for helping but I think my problem is not solve.

Comment: Please read my answer carefully :) I updated my answer with screenshots and an expalantion so it shouldn't be difficult to understand. you may have to refresh the page.

Comment: Hi @Siddhart, I have tried your code but i still get an error (to make sure I did copy it and modified to match my variables). here is my codes:

`"=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(" _
                        & offsetter & _
                        ","" "",""_""),""-"",""_""),""/"",""_""),""("",""""),"")"",""""))"`

Comment: `Now This formula will give you a #REF! error if the OUTPUT inside the =INDIRECT(OUTPUT) doesn't evaluate to a valid range.` Does it evaluate to a valid range? see the image i attached above